# How to resize material editor Node?

Tags: materials, node-editor

I can't stretch(resize) the node, instead it starts moving.

[image]

Comment: what Blender version is it? It must be a bug, it will probably be fixed

Comment: From my experience this only happens when you have multiple nodes selected. Any chance you have something else selected that is not in the image?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett .. Good point, mind you, it's showing active, so it should work even if others are selected?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. The node starts to move if it is selected (highlighted), if not then the size changes. In other words, to change the size, the node must not be selected (highlighted). )))